# How to add Labels Over the image. at four corners of image in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

i am Using **jQuery mobile.**

I currently have an image in a page.

I need to place 4 Labels at 4 corners **over the image**

**How to set Labels at 4 corners over the image.**

Comment: showing us some code that shows what you've attempted so far would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="imagepath" />
  <label class="label1">1</label>
  <label class="label2">2</label>
  <label class="label3">3</label>
  <label class="label4">4</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imgContainer{
  position: relative;
}
.label1, .label2, .label3, .label4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.label2{
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.label3{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.label4{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tahnk u very much for ur quick resonce and guidence